# How to trace events that make use of a particular input element

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, json

I am dealing with an input element inside of an ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC ASPX page with minified JavaScript. I don't have the C# source code for this page because it is not distributed, but I can still modify the .aspx file pertaining to this input element and inject my own JavaScript into the page.

The input element has some sort of value, property, or attribute on it that is used by the page to supply a value to a JSON object that is passed back to the server on submit.

I would like to trap any events that try to grab properties, attributes, or values from the element and debug the call stack to see where it's setting this JSON property. I would like to know what techniques or tools I can use to do this style of tracing, because I haven't been successful in finding the events that are called when this happens, particularly because inspecting elements with IE's F12 tools have lead to a dead end for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It allows you to see all the traffic (from all browsers, to and from all websites), and see the calls to servers and the responses.

For example you can turn it on, then go to the site you're working on, click or do whatever it needs, and check in Fiddler if there was a post or get, and see if the server responded with a json object, xml, or if it had a 200 code or 404 or something more.

I hope this is useful.